# Verify whether a tun interface (created by OpenVPN) offers access to the Internet

Tags: networking, vpn, internet, openvpn

My machine hosts 9 network interfaces: the physical one, `eth0`, and 8 created by OpenVPN clients (`tun0`, `tun1`, ... `tun7`).

Each of these interfaces should offer Internet access. But sometimes some don't, because the VPN server loses Internet access itself.

Is it possible to verify whether each of these interfaces offers Internet access at a given time? Something like `ping -I tun0 1.1.1.1` would be perfect, but unfortunately `ping -I` doesn't work with virtual interfaces. Any other ideas?

I'm redirecting some of the internet traffic through the different interfaces and am looking for a way to automatically change interface when one stops offering Internet access (and then restore things later on when the Internet connection is back).